# jQuery Click Stop Propagation

Tags: jquery

I have a simple setup, a table whose cells have checkboxes within them.  I have two events, one that responds to clicking on the checkboxes and another which responds to clicking on the "tr" elements. When I click on a checkbox I don't want the table row event to fire. I've tried `event.stopPropagation()` and `return false;` without any luck.  Here's a snippet:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
    alert("tr clicked");
});

$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("checkbox clicked");
});
```

With something like:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="something" name="something" /></td>
</tr>
```

If the change event fires the click event will also fire.  Any clues on how to stop the `tr` click event from firing if the checkbox is changed within the `td` element of the `tr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend this:

```
$( '#theTable' ).delegate( 'tr', 'click', function ( e ) {
    if ( $( e.target ).is( 'input:checkbox' ) ) { 
        alert( 'checkbox clicked' );
    } else {
        alert( 'tr clicked' );
    }        
});
```

So, you have **only one** click handler for the entire table.

Btw, you don't have to place all the code inside this one handler. You can have separate functions for each action (checkbox clicked VS row clicked), and then...

```
$( '#theTable' ).delegate( 'tr', 'click', function ( e ) {
    if ( $( e.target ).is( 'input:checkbox' ) ) { 
        checkboxClicked( e );
    } else {
        rowClicked( e );
    }        
});

function checkboxClicked ( e ) {
    // process event
}

function rowClicked ( e ) {
    // process event
}
```

Comment: This does work, but how's it different functionally from what I wrote? (other than that it works...)

Comment: This looks the safest because it means I don't have to handle multiple events. The other answers were also just what I needed, but this is most complete for my implementation.

Comment: @Kezzer In your code you bind separate click / change handlers to each row / checkbox. It is better to use event delegation for this. With event delegation, you bind one global click handler for the entire table, and then inside that click handler you determine what was clicked, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `click` instead of `change`. Seems to be working here http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/mGVv7/1/

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("checkbox clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.change` and `.click` are different events firing at different times during an action on a checkbox, so the handler for one can't affect the other. You could add a check in your click handler:

```
$("tr").click(function(event) {
  if (event.target.type == 'checkbox') return;
  alert("tr clicked");
});

$(":checkbox").change(function(event) {
  alert("checkbox clicked");
});
```

Or use the `.click` event for both handlers:

```
$("tr").click(function(event) {
  alert("tr clicked");
});

$(":checkbox").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert("checkbox clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the `.click()` event on the checkbox, not the `.change()` event.

By the time `.change()` is fired the click event has already been processed and bubbled back up the DOM to the parent elements.