# jQuery stop propagation move <a> href to tr click in table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table,

```
<table id="theTable">
    <tr><th>Theader</th><th></th></tr>
    <tr class="ahover">
    <td><a href="pankaka">Im a link</a></td>
    <td>Im a td in a tr</td></tr>
    <tr class="DarkBackground">
    <td><a href="pankaka">Im a link</a></td>
    <td>Im a td in a tr</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want each `<tr>` to be clickable, and it should navigate to the href of the  in the first td on each row.

This is what I've tried

```
$('table tr td:first-child a').each(function(){ var StopProp = Function('event', this.href.substring("javascript:".length) + ';
if(event.stopPropagation)    {event.stopPropagation();
    } else{
        event.cancelBubble = true;
    }'
);
    this.href = '#';
    $(this).click(StopProp);
});
$('.DarkBackground, .ahover').click(function(){
    $('#" + LeadsGridview.ClientID + " tr td:first-child a').unbind('click');
    $(this).find('a').click();
});
```

This worked *fine* at first, my colleague has helped me with is (I'm having problems understanding the first row though so I cant fix it). But then then something broke and again I get "too much recursion".

I read alot of different threads to find an answer, this seems to be cutting close: [jQuery Click Stop Propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445199/jquery-click-stop-propagation) but I'm not sure how to apply it to my problem. I've tried in this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DrczW/).

After some more research I found out you can do this via codebehind. (The table is a `<asp:Gridview>` that fetches data to each row from a database. Would that be a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#theTable tr:not(:first)').click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).find('td:first a').prop('href');
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Giving it a try, but Im not sure it will work. The link is actually an ajax request and displays that info in another tab on the same page :/